# How to get the id of a particular switch in a custom list view and check it

Tags: android, listview

This is my getView() code. I want to access a particular switch in this custom listview. What am i doing wrong ?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if(convertView==null)
            {
                //inflate the custom layout
                convertView = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

                //cache the views
                viewHolder.sw=(Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                viewHolder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                viewHolder.rollno=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roll);

                viewHolder.id=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID);

                //link the cached views to the convertview
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }
            else
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



            //set the data to be displayed

            viewHolder.name.setText(studentList.get(position).get("name").toString());
            viewHolder.rollno.setText(studentList.get(position).get("roll_no").toString());
            viewHolder.id.setText(studentList.get(position).get("id").toString());
            viewHolder.sw.setText("");

            for (int s : absentMarked) {

                Log.d("marked",Integer.toString(s));

                if(s==1){

                    Log.d("Entered","Yes");

                    viewHolder.sw=(Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                    viewHolder.sw.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
```

This is where problem exist. This checks all the switches to true. I want to access a particular Switch in my list View and check it. absentMarked is an array list which contains 0 and 1. I want to check the switch to true corresponding to the 1 value

```
for (int s : absentMarked) {

                Log.d("marked",Integer.toString(s));

                if(s==1){

                    Log.d("Entered","Yes");

                    viewHolder.sw=(Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                    viewHolder.sw.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What is absentMarked here ?

Comment: Which switch want to access?

Comment: viewHolder.sw is the toggle switch i want to access..

Comment: @AnkiiRawat absentMarked is an array list which contains 0 and 1. I want to check the switch to true corresponding to the 1 value

Comment: @MridulSKumar i suggest you should put absentMarked in Model and access that as `if(studentList.get(position).get("absentMarked")==1){

                    Log.d("Entered","Yes");
                    viewHolder.sw.setChecked(true);
                }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add field for AbsentMarked in Model.

```
   if(studentList.get(position).get("absentMarked")==1){ 
   Log.d("Entered","Yes");
   viewHolder.sw.setChecked(true); 
   }else{ viewHolder.sw.setChecked(false); }
```

and Add setOnCheckedChangeListner for Switch an toggle value of absentMarked as follows:

```
    sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
              setAbsentMarked(1);
            } else{
              setAbsentMarked(0);
        }
    });
```